# Computing combinations

Tags: r, biostatistics, bioinformatics

I am having a problem in getting all the combinations from my dataset. I need your suggestions and guidance in doing so.

I have a file, whose first column contains the regions and other file five column represents if a binding event takes place or not.

```
Region  TF1 TF2 TF3 TF4 TF5
Reg1    8   0   4   9   11
Reg2    2   0   0   4   0
Reg3    0   8   9   0   3
Reg4    6   82  8   0   4
```

Here the most prevalent combination is of TF1,TF3,TF4, TF5 & TF1, TF2, TF3, TF5.
.

I have a file of 1700 regions (rows) and 25 binding events(columns).

How can I get near to my desired result with some associated score for each combination.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Region  TF1 TF2 TF3 TF4 TF5
Reg1    8   0   4   9   11
Reg2    2   0   0   4   0
Reg3    0   8   9   0   3
Reg4    6   82  8   0   4", header = TRUE)
```

The following commands can be used to obtain the frequencies of the unique combinations of bindings:

```
tab <- table(apply(dat[ , -1] != 0, 1, paste, collapse = "."))

as.data.frame(setNames(tab, lapply(names(tab), function(x)
           paste(names(dat)[-1][as.logical(strsplit(x, "\\.")[[1]])], collapse = ", "))))
```

The output:

```
                Var1 Freq
1      TF2, TF3, TF5    1
2           TF1, TF4    1
3 TF1, TF3, TF4, TF5    1
4 TF1, TF2, TF3, TF5    1
```

Comment: Is it possible to associate the combination with any sort of scoring or p-value or z-score?

Comment: @Angelo Yes, the combinations could be associated with any other information. You should provide an example.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. Secondly how can I direct the output to a file? Thank you in advance

Comment: I did store the result in a variable for example in "result" Now how can I transfer the data stored in this variable to an excel file :(

Comment: @Angelo `write.csv2(result, row.names = FALSE, file = "filename.csv")`

Comment: Last one, How can I know which of the TF is most represented in different combinations?

Comment: @Angelo You can sort the rows of the `result` object by the values in `Freq` with this command: `result[order(result$Freq, decreasing = TRUE), ]`